# Error when using layout anchors with UIStackView

Tags: objective-c, swift

Trying to add a stackView and some children to it, but get layout errors. What am I doing wrong?

The problem seem to occur when the trailinAchors constant is lower then the leadingAchors constant.

```
    self.stackview.axis = .vertical
    self.stackview.alignment = .fill
    self.stackview.distribution = .fill
    self.stackview.spacing = 5
    self.addSubview(self.stackview)
    self.stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.stackview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.stackview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.stackview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.stackview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    // Holder
    let holderView = UIView()
    holderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.stackview.addArrangedSubview(holderView)

    // Subview
    let view3 = UIView()
    view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    holderView.addSubview(view3)

    view3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    view3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
```

Error:

```
    2017-06-30 17:38:37.124333+0200 XXXXX[83954:2132661] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028b680 H:|-(30)-[UIView:0x7f8dab565720]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8dab566620 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028b6d0 UIView:0x7f8dab565720.trailing == UIView:0x7f8dab566620.trailing - 30   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028b4a0 H:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7f8dab569320]   (active, names: '|': XXXXX.MultipleBarGraphsView:0x7f8dab561190'What are you doing' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028b3b0 UIStackView:0x7f8dab569320.trailing == XXXXX.MultipleBarGraphsView:0x7f8dab561190'Hur ofta svarar du r\U00e4tt?'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028b900 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' XXXXX.MultipleBarGraphsView:0x7f8dab561190'Hur ofta svarar du r\U00e4tt?'.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028af00 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7f8dab569320.leading == UIView:0x7f8dab566620.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028bbd0 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIView:0x7f8dab566620]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7f8dab569320 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028b6d0 UIView:0x7f8dab565720.trailing == UIView:0x7f8dab566620.trailing - 30   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that I called

```
layoutIfNeeded()
```

at the bottom of the function. When I removed this, the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

What view is this in?  I suspect that the leading and trailing anchors of the tableview's superview may have the same value (same location).  Make sure the tableview's superview is properly constrained to its own superview (could be the view controller) so the frame has a width and height > 0.